# Extracting decimal numbers from a string in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've tried lots of searches for this but I'm still not coming up with anything that works.

I have a range of strings in Column A

```
Amend.Clause_1.1.AddMCQ
Amend.Clause_1.1.AddNo
Amend.Clause_1.1.AddRepeat
Amend.Clause_1.13.AddRepeat
Amend.Clause_1.13.AddTitle
Amend.Clause_1.13.AddUTQ
Amend.Clause_2.8.Heading_Edit
Amend.Clause_2.8.MCQ
Amend.Clause_2.8.Remove
Amend.Clause_4.26.AddUTQ
Amend.Clause_4.26.Heading_Edit
Amend.Clause_4.26.MCQ
Amend.Clause_5.15.AddMCQ
Amend.Clause_5.15.AddNo
Amend.Clause_5.15.AddRepeat
```

As you can see, the numbers always start in the same place, after the underscore "_" at position 13.

I need to extract the decimal numbers from these strings into a new column so I'm left with 1.1, 1.13, 1.14, 4.26 etc.

I've tried all sorts of combos of MID, LEFT, LEN, RIGHT but to no avail, trying to find the position of the last period.

Could anyone explain how to accomplish this? Ideally I'd like to do this without VBA.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-excels-find-and-mid-to-extract-a-substring-when-you-dont-know-the-start-point/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - If the position of _ is not necessarily 13.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1,FIND("¬¬",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","¬¬",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))-FIND("_",A1,1)-1)
```

Or this if the _ is always 13

```
=MID(A1,14,FIND("¬¬",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","¬¬",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))-14)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("_",A1)+1,SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH("_",A1)+1)+1)-(SEARCH("_",A1)+1)))
```

Here's what inside `=VALUE(MID(...))`:

`A1` - the whole string itself

`SEARCH("_",A1)+1` - find the number starting position - right after `"_"`.

`SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH("_",A1)+1)+1)-(SEARCH("_",A1)+1)` - find number length - position of second `"."` after first `"."` minus number starting position.

Answer (score 1):

Try with three functions:

```
=MID(A1,14,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","#",3))-14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
=VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("_";A1));".";REPT(" ";LEN(A1));2);LEN(A1))))
```

assuming value is in A1

Comment: Thanks for your help - this formula generates an error though.

Comment: No, no error I did try it with your data, maybe you need to replace the fields separator ";" by "," (different regional settings) :)

Answer (score 0):

Far from ideal, but with a shorter formula than the solutions offered so far:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","_",3)
```

Catch is that formulae would then need to be converted to values, parsed with delimiter `_` (being careful to ensure Column data format is Text) and surplus columns deleted.

Answer (score -1):

When the string Amend.Clause_1.1.AddMCQ is in A1

```
=Find(".",A1,Find(".",A1)+1)
```

will give the position of the second decimal point, then you should be able to extract the decimal number.

The syntax is

FIND(find_text, within_text, [start_num])

Comment: So this looks for the second decimal point because it sets the start number after the position of the first? Smart

Comment: Yes, you could add 1 to the inner Find result to be sure it goes past the first decimal point.

Comment: As I suggested above adding 1 is indeed necessary, have now edited to include this